# How implement a cart in clean architecture?

Tags: android, rx-java2, clean-architecture, android-livedata

I have cart in my app and store `productId` and `count` in Sqlite db (Wraps with Room).

When fetching the `productList` from the server, in `Data` layer inject `count` of product to the received list and then pass to other layers to show on screen (etc. `RecyclerView`)

When user increases the count of a product, How should refresh view?

- Getting all of `productList` from server that is not efficient
- Updating data in the presentation layer (ViewHolder) that is duplication.
- Or what?

Do you have any advice or recommendation?

Comment: This functionality is often the responsibility of a "cache", which maintains currency of information about your environment. The cache would update counts and might send change lists to observers.

Comment: I don't want cache everything! and just productList receive from server and cart information receive from cache(local db). Do you say I cache productList too? @BobDalgleish

Comment: Cache the information that you need. If you only need a count, and you can keep the count just based on adds and deletes, then it should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by using android architecture component [**LiveData**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) because of its lifecycle aware and you can **observe** the list of the products once the user adds a new product to the list the live data object will notify your UI and updates your adapter,

in case you're using **firebase realtime database** as your app backend you can check this well detailed [tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html)

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I use LiveData in presentation and Rx in data layer. I have semantic problem, not in using a tool :)